# MS CRM 2011 Install Failure "Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.InstallConfigDatabaseAction failed."

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to install MS CRM 2011, and I continually get the

"Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.InstallConfigDatabaseAction failed.--->System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.---> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

Error. I've tried to uninstall and Reinstall SQL 2008. I have to apply the SP1 patch to it everytime I create an instance - which goes through ok. I don't get any errors in the wizard until it actually starts the installation process. Afterward I continually get this error. Here is a copy of the log:

```
11:49:22|  Error| Installer Complete: ConfigDBInstaller - Error encountered
11:49:22|Warning| Error reported while configuring _Deployment. Attempting rollback
11:49:22|   Info| ConfigDBInstaller: Beginning uninstall operation
11:49:22|   Info| Executing Uninstall action:Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.UnregisterRoleAction
11:49:22|   Info| UnregisterRoleAction does not apply since _Deployment is not a explicit server role.
11:49:22|   Info| CrmAction execution time; UnregisterRoleAction; 00:00:00.0050000
11:49:22|   Info| ConfigDBInstaller:  Uninstall completed
11:49:22|  Error| Install exception.System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.InstallConfigDatabaseAction failed. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
---> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName)
at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(DirectoryContext context)
at Microsoft.Crm.Admin.AdminService.ConfigDBSecurity.SystemUserService.GetCaseSafeName(String domain, String accountName)
at Microsoft.Crm.Admin.AdminService.ConfigDBSecurity.SystemUserService.GetCaseSafeName(String name)
at Microsoft.Crm.Admin.AdminService.ConfigDBSecurity.SystemUserService.Create(String name, Guid defaultOrganizationId)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.StandardConfigSqlStrategy.AddInitialUser()
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.DatabaseInstallerBase.Install()
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.InstallConfigDatabaseAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.ServerRoleInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.ComposedInstaller.InvokeInstall(Installer installer, IDictionary stateSaver)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.ComposedInstaller.InternalInstall(IDictionary stateSaver)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.ComposedInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.ServerSetup.Install(IDictionary data)
at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.SetupBase.ExecuteOperation()
11:49:22|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.ServerSetup.ExecuteOperation
11:49:22|   Info| ActivatePage(ServerSetupFinishPage)
```

Thanks, any and all help is much appreciated!

**edit** CRM 4.0 Was installed and working perfectly fine. I tried fresh install and upgrade of 2011 edition and im having these problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I had to reassign the Webserver and application roles on the server, then reinstall sql server. That fixed the issue. For some reason the sql server thought the name had changed or something - despite numerous reinstallations. Not sure why or how - but that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Are you an administrator on your domain? The CRM setup process adds some groups to AD, so you'll need access on the domain to create those groups if you are the one running the setup process.

Comment: yeah im a domain and schema admin. The checklist goes through ok i just cant figure out why i keep getting this problem. I installed CRM 4.0 perfectly fine without any problems

Comment: ok so now when i try to go and install CRM 4.0 im getting the same errors. I've completely removed sql 2008 and reinstalled it but I cant seem to get passed this error!